# How to implement SEH (Structured Exception Handling) in VB6?

Tags: vb6, exception, seh, structured-exception

Could someone provide some example on implementing SEH in VB6? Everything I've seen so far is in C++

Comment: You can still do a lot in VB6 to handle errors. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Handle an access violation caused by a third party component on exit.

Comment: "Access violation" is different from "Structured exception handling". You can't handle an "access violation" with VB6 error handling, nor C++ structured exception handling, nor yet with VB.Net Try...Catch structured exception handling. You need to report a bug to the vendor of the 3rd party component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic 6.0 (and earlier) doesn't implement structured exception handling. It was first introduced in [Visual Basic .NET (VB 7)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) with the following construct:

```
Try
    ' Logic
Catch e As Exception
    ' Error handling
End Try
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxtas1e(VS.80).aspx):

> In Visual Basic 6.0, you use
>   unstructured exception handling to
>   deal with errors in your code. Placing
>   the On Error statement at the
>   beginning of a block of code handles
>   any errors that occur within that
>   block. Unstructured exception handling
>   also employs the Error and Resume
>   statements.